# how to check username and password through url by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

i am developing hybrid application by using intel xdk tool and jquery mobile framework for UI. i am trying to implement login function which means i just type username and password and click submit button. while cliking button i am calling javascript function for checking username and password whether it is correct or not. this is my javascript function for login

```
 var user, pwd ;
 var xmlHttp = null;
 var val;
 $("#Login").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 user = $("#username").value() ;
 pwd = $("#password").value() ;
 validateForm();
});

    function validateForm() {
        var url ="http://schoolsmartconnect.com/android/parent_login.php?key=agile89rise98&username="+user+"&password="+pwd;                
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
        xmlHttp.open( "POST", Url, true );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
            if (val == "1") {
                window.location = "page2.html";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
            }
      }

    function ProcessRequest() 
    {
        if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) 
        {
            if ( xmlHttp.responseText == "1" ) 
            {

                var val = xmlHttp.responseText;

            }                 
        }

    }
```

this is my severside PHP script

```
<?php 
require_once 'db.php';

$user = base64_decode($_REQUEST['username']);
$pass = base64_decode($_REQUEST['password']);
$key = $_REQUEST['key'];
$password = md5($pass);
if($key=="agile89rise98"){
//echo $password;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puserprofile WHERE username ='$user' AND password = '$password' and Status=1");
$rownum = mysql_num_rows($query);

if(0 < $rownum)
{       
    echo 1; 
}
else
{
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puserprofile WHERE username ='$user' and Status=1");
    $rownum2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);
    if(0 == $rownum2) {
        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puserprofile WHERE password = '$password' and Status=1");
        $rownum3 = mysql_num_rows($query3);
        if (0 == $rownum3) {
        echo 0;
        }
        else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{5,31}$/', $user){
        echo "username invalid";
        }
        else {
        echo "Invalid username";
        }


    } else {    
        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puserprofile WHERE password = '$password' and Status=1");
        $rownum3 = mysql_num_rows($query3);
        if (0 == $rownum3) {
        echo "Invalid password";
        } else {
            echo 0;             
        }
    }   
}
}

?>
```

My Requirement:-

i am sure my php script is correct, but In my javascript function i have to send my username and password request to server and get response also, if my response is equal to "1" then it redirect appropriate page otherwise it should display error messages

Comment: is there a particular problem/issue that you are facing? if so then please modify the question to mention the relevant details of that.

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you have a typo in your url var, remove the last quote(").

Answer (score 0):

For your need, why don't you just retrieve username and password from the input fields instead of getting them from the url.
It will be easy enough to get the values from the input fields and validate them.

Do something like this

```
<input type="text" id="user"/>
<input type="password" id="pwd"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
```

And in the script, do this

```
var user, pwd ;
$("#submit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
user = $("#user").value() ;
pwd = $("#pwd").value() ;
validateForm();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Now the script will look like this

```
var user, pwd ;
 var xmlHttp = null;
 var val;
 $("#Login").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 user = $("#username").value() ;
 pwd = $("#password").value() ;
 validateForm();
});

function validateForm() {
    var url ="http://schoolsmartconnect.com/android/parent_login.php?key=agile89rise98&username="+user+"&password="+pwd;                
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
  }

function ProcessRequest() 
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( xmlHttp.responseText === "1" ) 
        {

            var val = xmlHttp.responseText;
            if (val == "1") {
                window.location = "page2.html";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
            }

        }                 
    }

}
```

Comment: i am getting username and password from html form by using these two lines  var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
var pw = document.loginform.pword.value; and store into  variable called un and pw after i need to send these two username and password into server by using that url. In url am sendind my username,password as a parameter, so i want to check whether it is correct or not, your answer is not relevant my question

Comment: Remove those two lines and Now instead of un and pw, send the user and pwd variables in the url. It will definitely work as per your requirement.

Comment: i edited my code as what you said but still i did not get  my expected output my doubt is xmlhttprequest could you please tell me whether the above code is correct or not?

Comment: There is one mistake in your code. The var `val` is defined and declared inside `ProcessRequest` method. So its not available in `validateForm()`. Just place the location changing code in the `ProcessRequest()` method

Comment: i tried with your updated code even though i didn't get expected output, this is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/qdwtT/ you can also check it

Comment: the fiddle url is not what it should be..Its not pointing to the correct fiddle..

Comment: variable `url` is wrong when you make the request in the `xmlHttp.open` method. Also try to make a `GET` request because you are sending the parameters in the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77180/discussion-between-kapil-garg-and-dawood-rizwan).